# VC rejecting hexadecimal floating-point constant

Tags: c, visual-studio, visual-studio-2008, floating-point, floating-accuracy

I'm writing a program which converts CIL bytecode to C source code for machine consumption.  I was concerned about inaccuracy in floating-point constants due to conversion to and from decimal.  After doing some research, I discovered that C (but not C++) is supposed to be able to accept a hexadecimal notation for floating-point constants.

I decided to try it out, but MS VC9 gives me errors no matter what I try.  Here is what I'm trying:

```
// Switches: /Od /D "WIN32" /D "_DEBUG" /D "_CONSOLE" /D "_UNICODE" /D "UNICODE" /FD /MDd /Fo"Debug\\" /Fd"Debug\vc90.pdb" /W3 /nologo /c /ZI /TC

#include <tchar.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    double d = 0x1.0p+1;    // error C2059
    //double d = 0x1p+1;    // doesn't work either
    //double d = 0x1p1;     // doesn't work either
    //double d = 0x1.0p1;   // doesn't work either

    printf( "%f\n", d );

    return 0;
}
```

I expected this to print out 2, from 1x2^1, but instead it gives me this compiler error:

```
error C2059: syntax error : 'bad suffix on number'
```

I realize C++ doesn't support this syntax (or so I've read,) but notice this is compiled with `/TC` so it should be straight C, and I used a `*.c` filename for good measure also.

Am I doing something wrong here, or is VC9 just not standards compliant?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There's nothing wrong with your code.  Floating-point hexadecimal constants were added to C in the C99 standard, but MSVC only supports the older C90 standard (with some extensions, like `//` single-line comments and the `long long` type).

Comment: Thank you for the confirmation; I was afraid it was something like that.  I guess I'll have to add a switch to output decimal scientific notation for pre-C99 compilers.

Answer (score 1):

C++17 standard added full support of C99 hexadecimal floating-point literals. Visual C++ will have them available in Visual Studio 2017 15.6 release.